Drag and Drop Child in angular
I have a problem with drag and drop with the tree components of primeNG, I have a folder tree with files in it when I want to drag and drop a folder into another folder it moves, so far everything is fine but when I go to look in this folder that I moved I find that the folder is empty, I can't find a way to also make the files in the folder
My file service :
 public nodeUpdate = new Subject<void>();
  files$ = this.filesSubject.asObservable();

  getFiles(): FileItem[] {
    return this.filesSubject.getValue();
  }

  updateFiles(files: FileItem[]) {
    this.filesSubject.next(files);
  }

  moveFolder(source: FileItem, target: FileItem): void {
    if (source.id === target.id) {
      console.error("Cannot move a folder to itself");
      return;
    }

    let allFiles = this.getFiles();
    const sourceCopy = this.deepCopyNode(source);
    allFiles = this.removeNode(allFiles, source.id);  
    this.addNodeToTarget(allFiles, sourceCopy, target.id);
    this.filesSubject.next(allFiles);
  }

  private removeNode(nodes: FileItem[], nodeId: number): FileItem[] {
    return nodes.reduce((acc: FileItem[], node: FileItem) => {
      if (node.id !== nodeId) {
        acc.push({
          ...node,
          children: node.children ? this.removeNode(node.children, nodeId) : []
        });
      }
      return acc;
    }, []);
  }

  private deepCopyNode(node: FileItem): FileItem {
    return {
      ...node,
      children: node.children ? node.children.map(child => this.deepCopyNode(child)) : []
    };
  }

  private addNodeToTarget(nodes: FileItem[], source: FileItem, targetId: number): void {
    const targetNode = this.findNodeById(targetId, nodes);
    if (targetNode && targetNode.itemtype === ITEMTYPE.folder) {
      if (!targetNode.children) {
        targetNode.children = [];
      }
      targetNode.children.push(source);
    } else {
      console.error("Target is not a folder or does not exist");
    }
  }

  public findNodeById(id: number, nodes: FileItem[]): FileItem | null {
    for (let node of nodes) {
      if (node.id === id) {
        return node;
      }
      if (node.children) {
        let found = this.findNodeById(id, node.children);
        if (found) return found;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}

I put console.log to see the status of my file and I can see that the file no longer has any children even though it is supposed to have them

please share the minimal reproducible code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated
